# how i can make thread for progress bar with pafy

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pafy

i'm trying to fix problem in my program and this problem is when i start download video the program not responding and i can't see also progress bar move so i tried used threading module but i can't fix problem so how i can fix problem

From this code I can download the video and send the data to another function to retrieve information that I use to connect it to the progress bar

```
def video(self):
    video_url = self.lineEdit_4.text()
    video_save = self.lineEdit_3.text()

    pafy_video = pafy.new(video_url)
    type_video = pafy_video.videostreams

    quality = self.comboBox.currentIndex()

    start_download = type_video[quality].download(filepath=video_save,callback=self.video_progressbar)
```

This code is received information from video function to connect with progress bar

```
def video_progressbar(self,total, recvd, ratio, rate, eta):
    self.progressBar_2.setValue(ratio * 100)
```

I use;python3.5 pyqt5 pafy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to move to another thread is to create a `QObject` that lives in another thread and execute that task in a slot. And that slot must be invoked through `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` or a signal.

#### `with QThread and QMetaObject::invokeMethod:`

```
import pafy
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.le_url = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bMt47wvK6u0")
        path = QtCore.QStandardPaths.writableLocation(QtCore.QStandardPaths.DownloadLocation)
        self.le_output = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(path)
        self.btn_quality = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Get qualities")
        self.combo_quality = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.btn_download = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Download")
        self.progressbar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(maximum=100)

        self.downloader = DownLoader()
        thread = QtCore.QThread(self)
        thread.start()
        self.downloader.moveToThread(thread)

        self.btn_quality.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked_quality)
        self.btn_download.clicked.connect(self.download)
        self.btn_download.setDisabled(True)
        self.downloader.progressChanged.connect(self.progressbar.setValue)
        self.downloader.qualitiesChanged.connect(self.update_qualityes)
        self.downloader.finished.connect(self.on_finished)

        form_lay = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(central_widget)
        form_lay.addRow("Url: ", self.le_url)
        form_lay.addRow(self.btn_quality)
        form_lay.addRow("qualities: ", self.combo_quality)
        form_lay.addRow("Output: ", self.le_output) 
        form_lay.addRow(self.btn_download)  
        form_lay.addRow(self.progressbar)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_finished(self):
        self.update_disables(False)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_clicked_quality(self):
        video_url = self.le_url.text()
        QtCore.QMetaObject.invokeMethod(self.downloader, "get_qualities",
            QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection,
            QtCore.Q_ARG(str, video_url))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(list)
    def update_qualityes(self, types_of_video):
        for t in types_of_video:
            self.combo_quality.addItem(str(t), t)
        self.btn_download.setDisabled(False)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def download(self):
        video_save = self.le_output.text()
        d = self.combo_quality.currentData()
        QtCore.QMetaObject.invokeMethod(self.downloader, "start_download",
            QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection,
            QtCore.Q_ARG(object, d),
            QtCore.Q_ARG(str, video_save))
        self.update_disables(True)

    def update_disables(self, state):
        self.combo_quality.setDisabled(state)
        self.btn_quality.setDisabled(state)
        self.le_output.setDisabled(state)
        self.le_url.setDisabled(state)
        self.btn_download.setDisabled(not state)

class DownLoader(QtCore.QObject):
    progressChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    qualitiesChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(list)
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def get_qualities(self, video_url):
        pafy_video = pafy.new(video_url)
        types_of_video = pafy_video.allstreams # videostreams
        self.qualitiesChanged.emit(types_of_video)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(object, str)
    def start_download(self, d, filepath):
        d.download(filepath=filepath, callback=self.callback)

    def callback(self, total, recvd, ratio, rate, eta):
        val = int(ratio * 100)
        self.progressChanged.emit(val)
        if val == 100:
            self.finished.emit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(320, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

#### `with threading.Thread`:

```
import pafy
import threading
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    qualitiesChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(list)
    progressChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.le_url = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bMt47wvK6u0")
        path = QtCore.QStandardPaths.writableLocation(QtCore.QStandardPaths.DownloadLocation)
        self.le_output = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(path)
        self.btn_quality = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Get qualities")
        self.combo_quality = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.btn_download = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Download")
        self.progressbar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(maximum=100)

        self.btn_quality.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked_quality)
        self.btn_download.clicked.connect(self.download)
        self.btn_download.setDisabled(True)
        self.progressChanged.connect(self.progressbar.setValue)
        self.qualitiesChanged.connect(self.update_qualityes)
        self.finished.connect(self.on_finished)

        form_lay = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(central_widget)
        form_lay.addRow("Url: ", self.le_url)
        form_lay.addRow(self.btn_quality)
        form_lay.addRow("qualities: ", self.combo_quality)
        form_lay.addRow("Output: ", self.le_output) 
        form_lay.addRow(self.btn_download)  
        form_lay.addRow(self.progressbar)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_finished(self):
        self.update_disables(False)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_clicked_quality(self):
        video_url = self.le_url.text()
        threading.Thread(target=self.get_qualities, args=(video_url,)).start()

    def get_qualities(self, video_url):
        pafy_video = pafy.new(video_url)
        types_of_video = pafy_video.allstreams # videostreams
        self.qualitiesChanged.emit(types_of_video)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(list)
    def update_qualityes(self, types_of_video):
        for t in types_of_video:
            self.combo_quality.addItem(str(t), t)
        self.btn_download.setDisabled(False)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def download(self):
        video_save = self.le_output.text()
        d = self.combo_quality.currentData()
        threading.Thread(target=d.download, kwargs={'filepath': video_save, 'callback': self.callback}, daemon=True).start()

    def callback(self, total, recvd, ratio, rate, eta):
        print(ratio)
        val = int(ratio * 100)
        self.progressChanged.emit(val)
        if val == 100:
            self.finished.emit()

    def update_disables(self, state):
        self.combo_quality.setDisabled(state)
        self.btn_quality.setDisabled(state)
        self.le_output.setDisabled(state)
        self.le_url.setDisabled(state)
        self.btn_download.setDisabled(not state)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(320, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thank your code is working perfectly but i can't use qthread for my code and i use QmainWindow

Comment: Because I understand that you are a 50% code so I tried to use qthread and did not succeed in solving the non-response problem

Comment: you just changed class

Comment: i will put my code to solve my problem by you and put qthread in right place

Comment: thank you i tried to read your code again and i understand now how i can use thread

Comment: @AbdoHassany I recommend you check the operation of QThread if you are going to work with PyQt since in the world of Qt it is used a lot. :-)